# Cannot make ipv6 ULA addresses work

Tags: ipv6, lan

I wanted to assign Unique Local Addresses (ULA) to a couple of machines inside my LAN alongside the link-local ones and the globally routable ones. I am currently running dual stack. 
I also wanted to keep them short, like `fd69:6666::`.

One machine is running Debian Jessie (kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64) and the other one Linux Mint 17.2 (kernel 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64).

After following this guide: [Set Up An IPv6 LAN with Linux](https://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/set-up-ipv6-lan-with-linux). 
I ended up with the following configuration:

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
address fd69:6666:: #fd69:7777:: on the other machine.
netmask 64
```

**/etc/radvd.conf:**

```
interface eth0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix fd69:6666::/64 { #fd69:7777:: on the other machine.
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
    };
}
```

Problem is that I end up having both machines with the `fd69:6666` prefix and nothing else! IPv6 connectivity stops working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using fd69::6666 instead. Using fd69:6666:: only sets the network part of the address. 
 Remember to change the netmask too! 
 This should be the result:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
address fd69::6666
netmask 64
```

Comment: Remarkably enough, radvd is not really needed. Perhaps because i didn't add the `autoconf 0` clause?

Comment: The Debian machine now lost its global IPv6 address. How can this be?

Comment: I would stick  to 64 bit netmask.

Comment: Why? Is it related to the debian machine losing its global address?

Comment: For some reason now `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/autoconf` is needed (plus waiting a few minutes). Add to sysctl.conf as needed.

Comment: Netmask fixed, asking a separate question for the sysctl issue.